# Why is "*\\Completions\\*" formatting used when specifying buffer names for display-buffer-alist?

Tags: regular-expressions, string

From [GNU Emacs Manual: 20.6.2:](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/emacs.html#Displaying-Buffers)

> If you prefer Emacs to display a temporary buffer in a different
>   fashion, we recommend to customize the variable `display-buffer-alist`
>   (see Choosing a Window for Display in The Emacs Lisp Reference
>   Manual). For example, to display `*Completions*` by splitting a window
>   as described in the previous section, use the following form in your
>   initialization file (see Init File):
>
> ```
> (customize-set-variable  
> 'display-buffer-alist  
> '(("\\*Completions\\* display-buffer-pop-up-window)))
> ```

I've used the code above in my `init` file, and it works, but I have a question. What are the `\\`s doing in the `Completions` buffer name? Does it make any difference if you just write `"*Completions*"` instead? I've tried this, and I can't see any difference, but I'm worried I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for `display-buffer-alist` (Use `C-h v` to describe the variable). You'll see that each entry consists of a condition and an action, and that the condition is either a regular expression or a function.

In your example, the string is interpreted as a regular expression. To match a literal `*` character, you can escape it (`\\*`) or put it in a character alternative  (`[*]`) . Generally a `*` in a regular expression means "zero or more" of whatever precedes it.

It happens to work in your example, but it could match names other than just `*Completions*`. More specifically, without the slashes you are creating a regular expression that will match "*Completion" followed by zero or more "s" characters.

The double slash is required by the Lisp string syntax, because a single slash is itself interpreted as a special character. (E.g. `"\n"` to represent a newline character.)

So:

- the Lisp string `"\\*foo\\*"`
- represents the character sequence `\*foo\*`
- which, when interpreted as a regular expression, will match the literal sequence of characters `*foo*`

Comment: I see, so the ` \\ ` stops the ` * ` being treated as a wildcard. But in that case, why isn't one ` \ ` enough?

Comment: That is due to how Emacs handles strings. The slash is itself a special character -- for example, the sequence `\n` in a string represents a newline. To include a literal slash in a string you need to escape that, `\\\`.

Comment: Ok, so if I've understood this correctly, \\ is used as the escape character because \ followed by certain other characters performs its own unique function?

Comment: (minor) An alternative to escaping it using `\\*` is to use `[*]`. So it is not exactly true that "*you need to escape it using `\\*`*".

Comment: True. Also I believe a `*` at the beginning of a regexp is treated as a literal, since there is nothing to apply it to, so you could just use `\\*` or `[*]` for the one at the end.

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks to your final three bullet points. I just didn't realize that the string `"\*"` would represent the character sequence `*`. Once I got that, the need for the second \`\\` became obvious.